# Optimize $x^2+y^2+2y$ over $x\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2\leq 2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$x^2+y^2+2y$$

$Z_{x}: 2x$

$Z_{y}: 2y+2$

$Z_{xx}: 2$

$Z_{yy}: 2$

D: 4

$2x=0\Rightarrow x=0$

$2y=2\Rightarrow y=-1$

so $(0,-1)$ is global minimum, how can I find the global maximum?

Comment: $x\leq$...what? $x\leq 1000$? $x\leq -1$?

Comment: @5xum Sorry, edited

Comment: There is no maximum on the whole space. To find the maximum on the specified domain, consider optimization on the boundary, which can be done by substitution or Lagrange multipliers. Note that the boundary is not smooth, as you can see by looking at the points $1,1$ and $1,-1$. So you need to treat the circular part of the boundary and the vertical line part of the boundary separately.

Comment: what does it mean "boundary is not smooth"?

Comment: In the disk we obviously maximise both $x^2+y^2$ and $y$ separately by taking $x=0,y=\sqrt2$. That also satisfies $x\le 1$, so it gives the maximum of $x^2+y^2+2y$ over the specified domain.

Comment: @almagest how did you find it?

Comment: @newhere. Surely it is obvious? The disk is precisely $x^2+y^2\le 2$, so we maximise $x^2+y^2$ by taking any point on the boundary. The point in the disk with the largest value of $y$ is $(0,\sqrt2)$.

Comment: @newhere You can't introduce a differentiable function $r(t)$ which traces out the boundary of this domain, because it has two "corners" where you switch between the vertical line and the circular arc. This lack of smoothness creates some minor problems which are best addressed by just dealing with the pieces separately.